# APNS - How to connect to feedback service

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, feedback

I searched apples documentation but i cant find any more solid references to feedback service for apns.  My goal is to connect to the feedback service of apns from my php server to check which tokens are invalid and update my database. Is feedback service not used anymore ? how to remove old dead device tokens then ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written a Python scrip that can send push notifications and checks for obsolete tokens.
You can find it here (shameless plug, but I think it is relevant here):

https://github.com/Joride/pushnotificationmakerandsender

Remember that Apple is updating its APNS service to a new protocol which makes it a lot easier to get what you are looking for. Check out the WWDC 2015 session on push notifications. There might already be some documentation for it too.